# Вопрос по библиотеке simplehtmldom

Tags: php, html

В мануале написано как форейчем проходит по элементам и вынимает различные атрибуты. У меня вот такая задача: элементы вывели зеброй, как мне лучше по ним пройтись, с учетом, что надо вынуть данные и внутри `one` и `two`?

```
<table id="catalog">
<tbody>
<tr class="one">
<tr class="two">
<tr class="one">
<tr class="two">
<tr class="one">
<tr class="two">
<tr class="one">
<tr class="two">
```

Еще вопрос: в процессе вывода данных на экран во время отладки подскажите, куда смотреть, как удобнее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Селекторы можно составлять не только по классам, но и по тегам. Почитайте про css.

```
$dom = new simple_html_dom();
$dom->load($html);

$trs = $dom->find("#catalog tr");
foreach ($trs as $tr) {
    echo $tr->class; // атрибут "class", т.е. one, two
    echo $tr->innertext; // html внутри tr
    $tr->find("что-то"); // поиск внутри tr
}
```

Про отладку я что-то не понял вопрос. Нужно больше конкретики.